# What's wrong with my autoloader?

Tags: php, require, autoload, spl, spl-autoload-register

I'm trying to register a few autoloaders and I get an HTTP 500. My error log says the following:

> [05-Aug-2013 04:32:38 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'LogicException' with message 'Function 'Autoloader::config' not
>   callable (non-static method Autoloader::config() should not be called
>   statically)' in /home2/canforce/public_html/index.php:5

There was some stack trace part on the end of the error log, but it came showed up in huge letters so I took it out, I didn't think it was important.

I think my autoloader should work based on what I've read but for some reason it doesn't, here's the code:

index.php

```
include("config/autoloader.php");
spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::config');
spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::controller');
spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::service');
```

config/autoloader.php

```
class Autoloader {
function config($class) {
    $file = 'config/' . $class . '.php';
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    }
}
function controller($class) {
    $file = 'presentation/controllers/' . $class . '.php';
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    }
}
function service($class) {
    $file = 'model/services/' . $class . '.php';
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you everything you need to fix the problem. You're calling non-static functions statically.

Comment: @Maerlyn You're right, if only I had read a bit more carefully. All that txt and big words overwhelmed me a bit after a long day of coding :/ It makes sense and it works, but it's weird none of the docs I read showed that you have to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the `Autoloader` class and then pass it to the register function.

```
include("config/autoloader.php");
$autoloader = new Autoloader();
spl_autoload_register(array($autoloader, 'loader'));
```